# How to split a paragraph into sentences when they contain words such as "U.S." and "Inc."

Tags: python

I'm writing a celebrity trivia quiz in python that takes clues from Wikipedia.

I'm using the following code to split the paragraphs into sentences:

```
sentences = line.split(". ")
```

It works for everything except when there's a word that ends in a period in the sentence. For example, "XXX is a U.S. senator." gets incorrectly split into "XXX is a U.S."

I've created a list of exceptions where I remove the period from such words:

```
line = line.replace("Dr. ", "Dr ").replace("Mr. ", "Mr ").replace("Gen. ", "Gen ").replace("No. ", "No ").replace("U.S. ", "US ")
```

But for anything not in the list (e.g. "U.K." or "Inc."), the sentence gets stopped at the word ending in a period.

I'm not sure how else I can approach this. How can I preserve these words while still splitting into sentences?

Comment: Look into using the NLTK library.

Comment: As suggested by Sujal Singh, using a character or character sequence as separator between sentences helps. That way you can split sentences using this separator. For example: "\n" is used to insert a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```py
paragraphs = full_content.split("\n\n")
```

Where `full_content` is the data you want to split into paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list of abbreviations with dot](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/).
You should add this list into a file and check that if . belong a word at the file, skip it